# Google API Request in PY Error: "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am receiving this error after running a couple thousand rows through the Google Api. I think it has something to do with the closing of the request. Code exampled below. Python Version 3.4.2 running Windows 7

```
import urllib.request, json, csv, time

def GoogPlacDetails(placeid,key):
  #making the url
  AUTH_KEY = key
  PLACEID = placeid
  MyUrl = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json'
           '?placeid=%s'
           '&sensor=false&key=%s') % (PLACEID, AUTH_KEY)
  #grabbing the JSON result
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(MyUrl, timeout=10)
  jsonRaw = response.read().decode('utf-8')
  response.close()  
  jsonData = json.loads(jsonRaw)
  return jsonData
```

Comment: I am assuming that you are importing: import json, urllib2? If so, then you may have a more helpful exception being generated. What happens when you put your code in a try except block?

Comment: Should i be importing urllib2 instead?

Comment: What happens when you try it? If your version of Python supports it, then yes.

Comment: I dont have that module i would assume because i have the newer Python 3 and it is now called urllib.request?

Comment: Do you only have Python 3 installed on your server, or do you also have Python 2.7 installed? Your error indicates that server has an issue with urllib. Not sure if you have multiple installations of Python on your server and they are stepping on each other. What does this tell you: ls /usr/bin/

Comment: I am not running off a server or a linux machine i am running it off a windows 7 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running < Python 3 Try this:

```
def GoogPlacDetails(placeid,key):
    print "Fetch data from URL"
    AUTH_KEY = key
    PLACEID = placeid
    fileName = 'data/googleJson.json'
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=',PLACEID,'&sensor=false&key=',AUTH_KEY

    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
        filePut = open(fileName, 'w')
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print(e.code)

        data = 0
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print(e.args)

        data = 0

    if data != 0: #validate url
        try:
            with open(fileName) as jsonGetData:             
                #add data
                filePut.write(data)
                filePut.close()

                j = json.load(jsonGetData)
                print "Json processed."
                return 1
        except Exception, e:
            print e

            raise
        else:
            pass
        finally:
            pass
    else:
        print url," Not available."
        return 0
#end GoogPlacDetails
```

Otherwise look at the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to tweak the above code for Python 3.

Comment: @deltabravo You should edit your question to inform others about: version of Python running, OS, Code changes etc. Only ask questions in the comments section. Cheers.